# scope of JS code in chroome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome function in brakets like below one throws error. Anybody can explain that behavior?

```
(function x () {return 4;})
x();
```

throws

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

In firefox and IE it works properly. I mean x is defined

Comment: I can't make it work on firefox.

Comment: You've wrapped the function in parentheses, creating an expression

Comment: You have a named function expression (see http://kangax.github.io/nfe/), and your sample will throw an error in any ES5-compliant environment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax (exp); but JSHint shows 2 things : you forgot a semicolon at the end of the first line, and x is not defined, as it's not the same (or parent) scope.